unreal engine mobile HDR off results in a reverse(flipped vertically) camera feed in AR template
As summarized in the title there is a problem with the unreal engine when trying to turn off the mobile HDR rendering for android devices. there are a few things messing with the me right now first is the lighting which is creating problems with lighting the meshes and the app not responding for a few seconds which needs optimization and a few others. after some research i found that turning mobile HDR off is a good solution for these problems and now im stuck with this problem can anybody help me or give me some directions coding or blueprint doesnt matter thanks in advance
i have found the camera feed material and tried to flip the UV Coordination vertically but didnt help maybe i was doing it the wrong way. there where two materials responsible for the camera feed i tried editing both but didnt work and i tried changing some other options in the projects settings but didnt work and now here im
this is the picture (vertically flipped)
this is the project setting option that is turned off

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

the previous comment was a mistake so i deleted it.

for reproducing this problem all you have to do is to open a new AR project in unreal engine using handheld AR template and turn off the turn off the mobile HDR setting in the Rendering section of the project settings doesn't matter if its shipping or the development packaging this results in a vertically flipped Camera feed the materials related to the camera feed are located in "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\AR\ARUtilities\Content\Materials"

as for the code module i have no idea where it is
